# Showing a function symbol inside an expression

Tags: output-formatting

Say I have a function with exponential term and I call it

```
v[x_, y_, z_] := 1/(1 + Exp[pone*x + ptwo*y + 1/z]);
```

Now, I perform some operation on it, for example, taking a derivative

```
D[v[x,y,z],x] = (E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z) pone)/(1 + E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z))^2
```

Since the original function contains exponential terms it will crop up again in the derivative expression. I would like to make the output of `D[]` (or well, anything else really) show me the name of the function or a symbol for it (something I can easily spot by looking), instead of its definition (which is hard to read when you have a few of them in and there are possibly similar, but not quite the same, terms around).

That is I would like the above to look like

```
   D[v[x,y,z],x] = (E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z) pone)/v[x,y,z]^2
```

even better if I could collect non-obvious things

```
 D[v[x,y,z],x] = (1/v[x,y,z]-1)*pone)/v[x,y,z]^2
```

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid giving a definition for `v`, and instead define it's derivative directly:

```
Clear[v]
v /: Derivative[1,0,0][v] = (1 - 1/v[##]) pone v[##]^2&;
```

I modified the definition from yours so that it agrees with using [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D). Now:

```
D[v[x,y,z], x]
```

> pone (1 - 1/v[x, y, z]) v[x, y, z]^2

Let's compare to the normal output of [`D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D) when you give a definition to `v`:

```
r1 = D[v[x,y,z], x] /. v[x_,y_,z_] -> 1/(1 + Exp[pone x + ptwo y + 1/z])
r2 = D[1/(1 + Exp[pone x + ptwo y + 1/z]), x]

r1===r2
```

> -((E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z) pone)/(1 + E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z))^2)
>
> -((E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z) pone)/(1 + E^(pone x + ptwo y + 1/z))^2)
>
> True